# Generic object factory

Tags: java, generics, factory

I got several objects that are created based on `DataObject` class.
So I'd like to make generic factory to construct them.

I'v tried something like this:

```
interface FactoryObject<T> {
    T create(DataObject data);
}

public class Factory {
    List<FactoryObject> fromDataObjectArray(DataObject[] data, Class<? extends FactoryObject> cls) {
        return Arrays.stream(Optional.ofNullable(data).orElse(new DataObject[0]))
               .map(d -> cls.create()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Finally, I'd like to call

```
List<MyClass> myClasses = Factory.fromDataObjectArray(data, MyClass.class);
```

But method `create()` cannot be resolved, how can I achieve what I need?

Comment: You want to pass in a factory instance, not the `Class` of the factory. Then you can call `factory.create(d)`.

Comment: Do you have an implementation of `FactoryObject<MyClass>` ?

Comment: Voted to close - unless more details are added - I can't determine what exactly you need, that the answer did not give you. Please give a precise *example* - perhaps pseudo-code - that shows how you would like it to work. I've read your comment on the answer, but still not sure what you are trying to do. Perhaps instead of talking about returning a list, show a simpler example where you pass in one value, and get one value back. Then show how that should work, for two different inputs.

Comment: `create()` - you are missing a parameter. Should be `.map(d -> cls.create(d)).

Comment: As per Thilo's comment, `Class<? extends IFactoryObject> cls` should instead be `IFactoryObject<T> fo`.  Then change my previous comment to `.map(d -> fo.create(d)).`. Usage is to pass in an instance, not the class: `Factory.fromDataObjectArray(data, new MyClass1());` Where `MyClass1` inherits from `IFactoryObject`. NOTE: Changed interface name to match convention of starting with `I`. That makes it easier for someone accustomed to the standard to understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you code, you want to create a list of instances; you could do something like that:

```
<T> List<T> fromDataObjectArray(DataObject[] data, FactoryObject<T> fac) {
    return Arrays.stream(Optional.ofNullable(data).orElse(new DataObject[0]))
           .map(d -> fac.create(d)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

UPDATE:

If I understand your comment below, you want a composite factory that will determine from a `DataObject` what is the actual factory you want to use to create your instance.

You could do something like this:

```
public class CompositeFactory<T> implements FactoryObject<T> {
    private final Function<DataObject,FactoryObject<? extends T>>[] funcs;

    public CompositeFactory(
            Function<DataObject,FactoryObject<? extends T>>... funcs) {
        this.funcs = funcs;
    }

    @Override
    public T create(DataObject data) {
        for (Function<DataObject,FactoryObject<? extends T>> func: funcs) {
            FactoryObject<? extends T> fac = func.apply(data);
            if (fac != null) {
                return fac.create(data);
            }
        }
        return null; // or throw an exception
    }
}
```

Another way to do that is conditional factories:

```
public class ConditionalFactory<T> implements FactoryObject<T> {
    private final Predicate<DataObject> cond;
    private final FactoryObject<? extends T> ifFac;
    private final FactoryObject<? extends T> elseFac;

    public ConditionalFactory(Predicate<DataObject> cond,
            FactoryObject<? extends T> ifFac,
            FactoryObject<? extends T> elseFac) {
        this.cond = cond;
        this.ifFac = ifFac;
        this.elseFac = elseFac;
    }

    @Override
    public T create(DataObject data) {
        return (cond.test(data) ? ifFac : elseFac).create(data);
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

Exemple: let's say you have the following classes:

```
class MyClass1 extends MyClass {
    public MyClass1(DataObject data) {
    }
}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass {
    public MyClass2(DataObject data) {
    }
}
```

...

and the corresponding factories:

```
FactoryObject<MyClass1> fac1 = (data) -> new MyClass1(data);
FactoryObject<MyClass2> fac2 = (data) -> new MyClass2(data);
FactoryObject<MyClass3> fac3 = (data) -> new MyClass3(data);
...
```

and let's say you can determine the actual class from the value of `DataObject.getType()`:

You could do:

```
FactoryObject<MyClass> fact = new CompositeFactory<MyClass>(
    (data)-> data.getType().equals("value1") ? fac1 : null,
    (data)-> data.getType().equals("value2") ? fac2 : null,
    (data)-> data.getType().equals("value3") ? fac3 : null,
    ...
);
```

you could also do:

```
FactoryObject<MyClass> fac = new CompositeFactory<MyClass>(
    (data)->{
        switch (data.getType()) {
            case "value1":
                return fac1;
            case "value2":
                return fac2;
    ...
            default:
                return null;
        }
    });
```

or:

```
FactoryObject<MyClass> fac = new ConditionalFactory<MyClass>(
        (data)->data.getType().equals("value1"), fac1,
        new ConditionalFactory<MyClass>(
                (data)->data.getType().equals("value2"), fac2,
                fac3));
```

Comment: Not quite. I'm having `DataObject[]` which I want to transform to `List<MyClass>`. There are several implementations of `MyClass` and each one implements `FactoryObject`. So I'd like to create one generic factory method that will return `List` of `MyClass`, `MyClass1`, `MyClass2`, depends on what I pass as a parameter.